# return a result from the outer function after calling async function in the inner function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function to read a file and then process it line by line, calculating max of each line and save it to result and then return it.

The problem is I got `Promise {undifned}`.

I checked the result in the last then and it is fine but I want to return it from the main function.

```js
const readMyFile = async (FilePath) => {


    var result;
    processLineByLine(FilePath).then(lines => {
        let r = 0
        lines.map(line => {
            r += Math.max(...line);
        })

        return r;
    }).then(
        (r) => result = r  
 // result is fine up to here, how to make the outer function returns 
// this result ???
    )

    return result;
}
```

and this the processByline:

```js
async function processLineByLine(path) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

    let _lines = [];
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        let rawValues = line.split(/\t/).map(e => Number(e))
        _lines.push(rawValues);
        // console.log(lines);
    }

    return _lines
}
```

Comment: Just use `await` in `readMyFile` as well! You don't even need that `.then()` call. Alternatively, always `return` the promise (chains) you are creating.

Comment: i add the await before lines and it returns promise pending

Comment: Of course it does, `readMyFile` is asynchronous and returns a promise. Where are you calling it? What do you want to do with the result? You will need to wait for it.

Comment: If by "*I want to return it from the main function.*" you meant that you want it to synchronously return the result, that is impossible.

Comment: `for await (const line of rl) {` <-- makes no sense that await is there

Comment: @Bergi thank you thank you very much .. I just got the result after calling the .then on the outer function call

Comment: @epascarello this from the documentation they put it like this, because it is reading the lines async.

Comment: @epascarello I'm pretty certain that `rl` implements an asynchronous iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that you can access the returned value of the `async function processLineByLine()` after you call it, and you need use `then` to access that returned value.

so the answer is :

```
processLineByLine('pth/to/the/file').then(lines => { console.log(lines) })
```